# How to post data to HTTP server using Java

Tags: java, http, google-calendar-api

In my Java script I can list the My calendar events :

```
String pageToken = null;
do {
    Events events= null;
    try {
        events = service.events().list(CALENDAR_ID).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CalendarService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    List<Event> items = events.getItems();
    for (Event event : items) {
        System.out.println(event.getSummary());
        System.out.println(event.getStart());
    }
    pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
} while (pageToken != null);
```

I wonder how I can send this information via http to a server? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to send data to a server, it's better to ask a different question, like: "How to post data to HTTP server using Java". The problem you're running into doesn't necessarily have anything to do with google-callendar itself.

Comment: @Jaap but the formats (and content-types) of data (if any!) accepted by a server vary depending on the server, so the server *does* matter. And so does whether it uses POST, PUT, GET and/or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an HTTP client, such as [Netty HTTP Client](https://github.com/timboudreau/netty-http-client) or [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/).

This is an [example taken from Apache HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpPost.java):

```
/**
 * Elemental example for executing multiple POST requests sequentially.
 */
public class ElementalHttpPost {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpProcessor httpproc = HttpProcessorBuilder.create()
            .add(new RequestContent())
            .add(new RequestTargetHost())
            .add(new RequestConnControl())
            .add(new RequestUserAgent("Test/1.1"))
            .add(new RequestExpectContinue(true)).build();

        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();

        HttpCoreContext coreContext = HttpCoreContext.create();
        HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080);
        coreContext.setTargetHost(host);

        DefaultBHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultBHttpClientConnection(8 * 1024);
        ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE;

        try {

            HttpEntity[] requestBodies = {
                    new StringEntity(
                            "This is the first test request",
                            ContentType.create("text/plain", Consts.UTF_8)),
                    new ByteArrayEntity(
                            "This is the second test request".getBytes(Consts.UTF_8),
                            ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM),
                    new InputStreamEntity(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                    "This is the third test request (will be chunked)"
                                    .getBytes(Consts.UTF_8)),
                            ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < requestBodies.length; i++) {
                if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                    conn.bind(socket);
                }
                BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST",
                        "/servlets-examples/servlet/RequestInfoExample");
                request.setEntity(requestBodies[i]);
                System.out.println(">> Request URI: " + request.getRequestLine().getUri());

                httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, coreContext);
                HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, coreContext);
                httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, coreContext);

                System.out.println("<< Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                System.out.println("==============");
                if (!connStrategy.keepAlive(response, coreContext)) {
                    conn.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection kept alive...");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use Java's builtin `URLConnection` with a URL of scheme http: or https:. But your example only connects and receives data, it doesn't send data, which is the question.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, you could use the fragile `HttpURLConnection` mechanism, but then you'd be lacking timeout, retries, connection pooling, etc. Anyways, I'll edit my answer so that it shows a POST example. Thanks for pointing this out.